# Reachability in digraphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

I have a problem that is reducible to (efficiently) determining the reachability of a node in a fully dynamic planar digraph.

I'm aware of ["A fully dynamic data structure for reachability in planar digraphs"](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-57273-2_72) which provides $O(n^{2/3} \log n)$ query with a $O(n)$-space data structure.

Can this be / has this been bettered?

If all my queries have the same source node, is there a more efficient (in time/space/both) way?

Are there any other related literature that deals with more efficient queries albeit with more restrictions imposed on the digraph?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Another paper on this topic that you may find useful is Mikkel Thorup's [Compact oracles for reachability and approximate distances in planar digraphs](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1039488.1039493),  *J. ACM*  51  (2004),  no. 6, 993-1024.  The abstract says:

> It is shown that a planar digraph can be preprocessed in near-linear time, producing a near-linear space oracle that can answer reachability queries in constant time. The oracle can be distributed as an $O(\log n)$ space label for each vertex and then we can determine if one vertex can reach another considering their two labels only.
>   The approach generalizes to give a near-linear space approximate distances oracle for a weighted planar digraph.  With weights drawn from $\lbrace 0, \ldots, N\rbrace$, it approximates distances within a factor $(1+\epsilon)$
>   in $O(\log \log(nN) + 1/\epsilon)$ time. Our scheme can be extended to find and route along correspondingly short dipaths.

Comment: This has been improved to linear-time linear-space preprocessing in https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5867 .